# Why does the xml-to-json policy result in an empty body when using it in the inbound policies?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Document reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#example-1

A snippet from my "inbound processing" policies:

```
<inbound>
   <base />
   <xml-to-json kind="direct" apply="always" consider-accept-header="false" />
</inbound>
```

**Problem:**
When I apply this policy in "inbound processing" the backend API (`Logic App`) that is called is given an empty body. The API receiving this request shows `Content-Length = 0`.

Results from trace:

```
xml-to-json (0.697 ms)
"XML-to-JSON policy was applied. Original Content-Length header was removed as its value was invalidated. Content-Type header was set to 'application/json'."
```

---

**Notes:**
When I apply this exact same policy in the "outbound processing" policies, I get the result I am expecting as JSON.

Basic XML example I am sending:

```
<note>
    <to>PersonOne</to>
    <from>PersonTwo</from>
    <heading>Test</heading>
    <body>Example</body>
</note>
```

Result I get when policy is applied to in "outbound policies" section (This is working as expected):

```
{
    "note": {
        "to": "PersonOne",
        "from": "PersonTwo",
        "heading": "Test",
        "body": "Example"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a simple scenario just using the `xml-to-json` policy and it did work as expected. Do you have any other policies that maybe are affecting the request body?

Comment: @PramodValavala-MSFT - I had tried to use just the single policy and it was still doing the same thing. Maybe knowing that the resource receiving this data is a `Logic App` would help? I have a simple Logic App that is setup as a trigger to receive this. I will try again today and simplify everything and see if there is anything else inbound that would do this. I'll post back today with some news. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a dump of request you're making to test policy in inbound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the original Content-Length header being removed when APIM does the conversion from XML to JSON. If you do a test request in APIM and look in the trace console you'll see a message like this:

> "XML-to-JSON policy was applied. Original Content-Length header was
> removed as its value was invalidated. Content-Type header was set to
> 'application/json'."

APIM replaces the header with

> Transfer-Encoding: chunked

and sets Content-Length to 0. Unfortunately Logic Apps don't support [chunked encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) on triggers (only on some [actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages)) so aren't able to handle the request.